# on Scroll animate scrollTop to move div up and fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

I am trying to animate a **header div** (height: 100px;) to move to the top of the screen when the user scrolls down. when it's at the top I'd like to fix it there. As the div moves to the top of the screen it passes over a **banner div** (height: 400px;), I have made the **banner div** fade out depending on how close the **header div** is to the top.

When the **header div** is fixed to the top and the **banner div** fully faded out I'd like an upward scroll to re-animate the **header div** to move back to it's original position (margin-top: 400;) and the **banner div** to fade back in.

I have created a JSFiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/xm33Laag/

```
see JSfiddle
```

Although it's not working like my local version :S

I can get the **header div** to go to the top but I can't get it to come back down. I also want my animation to look like this example : http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

I don't want to simply use fullPage.js because I only want it for this function. I don't need the myriad options that come with including it.

with the above ideal example, you can see that a single scroll will initiate the animation, and there's no initial jerking before the animation starts. I really like this!

My animation will initiate after you scroll, meaning that the initial scroll makes the viewer view 100px of snappy scrolling, then the animation. I'd like it to be one.

Thanks!

Comment: Letting an interval run indefinitely isn't such a great idea. Here's an approach that only sets a timeout when the user actually scrolls - and keeps clearing it until scrolling has stopped (then after 200ms it will fire). https://jsfiddle.net/xm33Laag/11/ For the rest I have to say it's quite unclear what you're after exactly.

Comment: Hey Shikkediel thanks for the advice!
Yeah I'm having trouble explaining myself haha! I guess I want the **header div** to smoothly move to the top when the user scrolls down, stay there, then smoothly come back to it's original spot once the user has reached the top of the page and scrolls upward

Comment: One more approach added, @Mikey. Should be smooth across browsers with the initial scroll now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a go at what I get as the gist of it. Slightly changed the CSS, giving the main content below the top margin instead of `.header`. It was a bit easier to code it that way.

Here's the live example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azrwog?editors=001

And the JavaScript (changed that a lot) :

```
var previous = 0, delta, initial = true, stopped;

$(window).scroll(function() {

clearTimeout(stopped);
var fromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
if (fromtop-previous > 0) delta = -1;
else delta = 1;
previous = fromtop;

if (fromtop < 400) {
var factor = 400-fromtop;
$('.banner').css({'height': factor, 'opacity': factor/400});
$('.header').removeClass('fixed');
if (delta == -1 && initial) firstScroll();
else if (delta == 1) scrollAction();
}
else $('.header').addClass('fixed');
});

function firstScroll() {
initial = false;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 800);
}

function scrollAction() {stopped = setTimeout(function() {goTop()}, 200)}

function goTop() {
var topoffset = $(window).scrollTop();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2*topoffset, function() {
initial = true;
});
}
```

Another solution update - cross browser smooth, using the [mousewheel.js plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/) :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEoGxG?editors=001

```
var fromtop, initial = true, stopped;

$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

if (!initial) $('html, body').finish();

$(window).scroll(function() {

clearTimeout(stopped);
fromtop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (fromtop <= 400) {
changeOpacity();
$('.header').removeClass('fixed');
if (delta == 1) scrollAction();
}
else $('.header').addClass('fixed');
});

if (initial) {
if (delta == -1) $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 400}, 800, function() {
initial = false;
});
return false;
}
});

function scrollAction() {stopped = setTimeout(function() {goTop()}, 200)}

function changeOpacity() {
var factor = 400-fromtop;
$('.banner').css({'height': factor, 'opacity': factor/400});
}

function goTop() {
var topoffset = $(window).scrollTop();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2*topoffset, function() {
initial = true;
});
}
```

Update - one line of code added to prevent 'sticking' after the initial scroll :

```
if (!initial) $('html, body').finish();
```

Comment: SOO CLOSE!!! It's basically perfect, all I want to change is that when you scroll the header will make a sharp jump up (for me in chrome it's 100px) - then it will animate. I'd love to get rid of this sharp jump and make it one smooth animation.
this example has the effect I'm talking about - http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage THANK YOU SO MUCH Shikkediel !

Comment: Updated, think it's exactly as requested now. B-)

Comment: It still has an initial jerk upward or downward. But I'm sure it will do! Thank's again shikkediel !

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. I didn't notice because I'm testing on Firefox with smooth scroll. I could fix that but it would have to be done with `mousewheel`  for which at this point the best option is to use a (small) plugin. https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/ If you like I could recode a bit. It'll eliminate the jerkiness across browsers. Don't believe it can be fixed with `.scroll` alone. That always needs an initial trigger (causing the movement you mentioned).

Comment: Oh my That's beautiful! I'm using chrome and still getting the jerking on the way back down. Thank you so much Shikkediel ! This helps so much!

Comment: You're welcome of course. Did you maybe mean on the way back *up*? That is sort of unavoidable because there's no way to really know at which point exactly the user will enter the top 400 pixels of the page. Scroll is something you can't prevent the default action of (it *is* the default I learned here). So when it goes, there's no way to stop it... unless you do all of the page with mousewheel and jQuery animation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, No biggie, the hiding of the banner initially is so nice anyway haha! Thank you again for your time and knowledge!!! Have a wonderful day (:

Comment: Cheers, to you as well. Glad to help out.

Comment: Ohh damn I just noticed a pretty big bug! if you reload the page and your inital scroll down is just one notch everything works fine, but if your initial scroll is long and goes over multiple notches scrolling of the page breaks :( - to be more specific, scrolling begins to act normally after you 'break' it, then keep scrolling down, almost as if it's 'catching up'?

Comment: You've done so much Shikkediel ! Don't worry about fixing it if you don't want to! I'm more than happy to take the baton and figure the rest out!

Comment: Fixed it already. Hadn't noticed it myself but that's the way it usually goes (quirks showing up). :-)

Comment: Again.. Beautiful! I'm going to look into this myself, but may as well ask seeing as this is Stack Overflow.. Is it possible to make this work for touch devices? Currently I'm testing this in chrome. I understand that touch scrolling doesn't initiate the .mousewheel event.

Comment: Are you testing on a touch device? I can't myself actually and haven't found anything that emulates it reliably. But `mousewheel` should default to scroll on mobile, from the feedback that I got. Good touch support would be to add swipe (touch events) but that's a whole other piece of script. Have a look at my page though, mousewheel to scroll (instantaneous, not animated) and swipe as well. http://ataredo.com/ Source files should be easy to read. For a longer discussion, we may better seek another medium than the comments though... or you could possibly start a new topic on it.

Comment: I uploaded my local version of the project to here to test it: http://thewild.com.au/threeball/ And the functions aren't initiating. Are you sure touch-swipes will initiate a .mousewheel event?

Comment: Not sure how the chat works here but maybe you could start a topic on CSS-tricks.com, there is more room for dialogue like this and I am also an active member there. Touch events won't trigger mousewheel, they are a whole set of other functions and could be a good additional feature to support. Default momentum scroll should have a nice effect on your animation though. The issue with the script is caused by it being commented out with `/* ... */` when it ends up on the server.

Comment: Script runs like a charm when I insert it... I think you would have to remove `$(document).ready()` around it. The CMS creates one by default so it will be nested which could cause the issue. Earlier suggestion I made isn't correct, I think.